# My website is showing some random page on mobile but on desktop it's fine

Tags: domain-name-system

My website countontech.com is showing some random advertisement page on mobile but on desktop it's working fine. I have contacted to my web hosting provider but he is saying that it's not from his side.

[Here is screenshot of website on desktop (it's fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzZaq.png)

[Here is a random advertisement page i am getting on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc0WB.png)

Comment: Did you recently change the DNS records or nameservers for the domain? What you're seeing on mobile looks like a parked domain.

Comment: yes i have changed DNS 3 hours ago

Comment: @NishantBhakta Sounds like your mobile is getting a cached DNS record. Depending on the TTL, it could take up to a day or two to see the site properly.

Comment: it started the same again. who should i contact, host provider or domain provider ?

Answer (score -1):

Check the DNS of both. Restart you phone and clear cache.

Comment: what does it means "both" here. hosting provider just gave me two DNS and i have updated it as name server 1 and name server 2. I started my blog today so i don't know much.